# Can't serve statics with Nginx on DigitalOcean VPS for Django

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx, gunicorn

Hi I am trying to serve statics using Django and Nginx on a VPS to get my project live. My settings.py includes following.

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
STATIC_URL = '/static/
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', 'static')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', 'media')
```

My project folder includes:

```
static
----static
----static-only
----media
----templates
```

In Nginx I got following:

```
upstream gunicorn_server {
# fail_timeout=0 means we always retry an upstream even if it failed
# to return a good HTTP response (in case the Unicorn master nukes a
# single worker for timing out).
server 127.0.0.1:9000 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {

listen   80;
server_name example.com;
keepalive_timeout 5;
client_max_body_size 4G;

access_log /home/projectuser/logs/nginx-access.log;
error_log /home/projectuser/logs/nginx-error.log;

location /static/ {
    alias   /venv/project/static/static;
}

location /media/ {
    alias   /venv/project/static/media;
}
location / {

    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    if (!-f $request_filename) {
        proxy_pass http://gunicorn_server;
        break;
    }
 }

}
```

I can't serve static no matter what and admin panel css is not showing up.

Please advise asap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing `static` and `media` blocks this way:

```
location /static/ {
    root   /venv/project/static;
}

location /media/ {
    root   /venv/project/static;
}
```

This way, the `http://example.com/static/admin/css/dashboard.css` will be searched as `/venv/project/static/static/admin/css/dashboard.css` on the filesystem.

P.S. Also instead of `if (!-f $request_filename)` it's better to use `try_files`: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files

Comment: I've changed locations and changed variables accordingly in settings.py and in nginx both. I still get: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) for following files:
http://example.com/static/admin/css/base.css  
http://example.com/static/admin/css/dashboard.css 

http://example.com/static/admin/css/base.css  

http://example.com/static/admin/css/dashboard.css

Comment: Edited the answer to add a little example. Then, according to the folder structure you provided in the question there's no `admin` folder in `static/static/` folder, and that's the problem. Btw, your `alias` should work the same way too, but they need a slash at the end.

Comment: Glad, that it helped! But what do you mean "without static front of it", explain please?

Comment: I added /venv/project/static and in inspect elements it was showing that its trying to render it from static/static. But I only had one static so I removed /static from the Nginx and instead used /mysource/myenv/myproject and it worked fine for me

Comment: But now stuck because I have templates stored in /template folder same location as static but how to serve those? Do I need to mention my templates in Nginx as well because technically my base template should be rendered with help of urls.py. But Its not showing up. What are the simplest settings for templates?

Comment: Templates are pages with placeholders for data from variables. This placeholders are filled in with the data by Django. So the templates are served by Django via gunicorn and not nginx directly, so there's no special setting for it in nginx. Usually templates are specified in Django's view functions/classes, so see Django docs on using templates.